# gnuplot, draw only the legend and not the graph plot

Tags: gnuplot

I have an interactive perl script which uses data from mysql to generate many plots through the Chart::Gnuplot package. There are times when the graph size is overloaded with too many plots.

I would option to generate the gnuplot image containing only the legend (no graph).

Comment: Could you add a bit of example code?  What do you want the titles to contain?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this would help, but...

```
plot [0:1] [0:1] NaN title "Hello" #Just the label in the legend.
```

or...

```
plot sin(x),NaN title "Boo"  #Plots sin(x) (properly labelled) and a second label "Boo"
```

Of course, this still has the border and other things.  You can unset those...`unset border` and `unset tics`