# Output gnuplot legend in separate file

Tags: gnuplot

I have a gnuplot script that generates several plots which I later use in a latex document.  I don't want to repeat the legend in every plot so right now I have `set nokey` so that the legend is not displayed at all.  However, I would like to output the legend in a separate file.

If I can't do this with a script then I can generate a graph and then crop out the legend with an image editing program.  But I would prefer to have the script generate the legend so that the legend will be automatically updated if I ever make other changes to the script that would effect the legend.

Is it possible to output only the legend without the associated plot data?  If so how might that be done?

Comment: This thread might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282192/gnuplot-draw-only-the-legend-and-not-the-graph-plot